# Check if URL has valid page

Tags: vb.net, url, httpwebrequest, response

I want to check if URL has valid page (not 404, just 200).

Code I've tried:

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(myurl), HttpWebRequest)
request.KeepAlive = True
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
If response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
    MsgBox("OK")
End If
```

Yet every URL that I enter leaves OK response, even if I enter `http://mywebsite.com/blahblah`.

It's not same on all websites (works fine with [example.com](http://example.com/)), but it doesn't work on my website. **Why?**

*In my browser I see 404 page, but code says it's **OK***.

Edit: Just to mention that my website has Cloudflare on.

Comment: What you are doing is fine, by the way `http://mywebsite.com/blahblah` is a valid site and returns ok... Also a 404 just means the page isnt found on the server, status will return ok even if a page isnt found and the server was reached and responded...

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Is there any way I can know if page is available on the server?

Comment: What you could do is read the webresponse into a streamreader, the pages code and then check it for a 404...

Comment: Already did it, yet response's HTML says that i need to enable javascript in my browser. I've added some headers (including user agent) to the request, yet I still have same problem.

Comment: Just a thought, have you checked that the site isn't protected with such a service like cloud flare? they set a cookie using javascript. You need to add that if so.

Comment: Yeah it has Cloudflare protection.. How can i allow javascript with cookie?

Comment: The idea is to protect the website from scanning for vulnerabilities amongst other things etc. You need to look in to setting the cookie, or getting the cookie set from the javascript on the page. I think this has been done. If you are able to maybe you could use the Web Browser control to get the cookie with javascript enable, then transfer it using a Cookie Container, or just use the wb control if that is enough.

Comment: @Pure it's not just about a cookie rather the headers themselves and a few other things.

Comment: That's correct, headers must be set including the cookie. You can do it but I suggest using the web browser control, otherwise it's going to be quite a long winded solution.

Comment: As i've already said above i have added headers, including cookie container. @Pure i need this to be quick, using web browser to load whole HTML of website would take too long as i want to check many URLs :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and see if it work's for you... As mentioned above in my comment's:

> A 404 just means the page isn't found on the server, status will return ok even if a page isn't found and the server was reached and responded

```
Public Class WebPage
        Public Property PageSource As String = String.Empty
        Public Property Status As HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound
        Public Property WebError As String = String.Empty
    End Class

    Public Shared Function GetWebPage(ByVal Website As String) As WebPage
    Dim web As New WebPage() With {.Status = HttpStatusCode.OK}
    Try
        Using source As New System.Net.WebClient()
            web.PageSource = source.DownloadString(Website)
        End Using

        Return web
    Catch exweb As WebException
        If exweb.Status = WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError AndAlso exweb.Message.Contains("404") Then
            web.Status = HttpStatusCode.NotFound
        Else
            web.Status = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest            
        End If
        web.WebError = exweb.Message
    Catch ex As Exception
        web.Status = HttpStatusCode.NotFound
        web.WebError = ex.Message
    End Try

    Return web
End Function
```

**Usage Example**

```
Dim webObj As WebPage = GetWebPage("THESITE")
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(webObj.WebError) Then
   MessageBox.Show(webObj.WebError)
ElseIf webObj.Status = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
   MessageBox.Show("OK")
End If
```

Comment: This would work unfortunately it won't help when the page is protected by cloudflare.

Comment: @Pure that is an easy change to code, but user didn't mention anything about cloudflare.

Comment: @Pure I will amend my comment above, user mentioned that in a ***comment*** I did not see. Also circumventing that protection I wouldn't put here, the user can look into that...

Comment: An easy code change? I would like to see that. I've sent it done before somewhere but I can't remember it being easy. Something I'd like to see!

Comment: As @Pure said, your code works fine on other websites but doesn't on mine.

Comment: @bananamen because you are using CloudFlare in which you failed to mention in your post, please update it and not in the comment's. Also you can get around CloudFlare, but me posting that I will not do because it will be patched... and I wont condone behavior that circumvents this.

Comment: I will, thanks for your answer. Someone will find this helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want.

```
Function URLExists(url As String) As Boolean
    Dim Request As Object
    Dim ff As Integer
    Dim rc As Variant

    On Error GoTo EndNow
    Set Request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    With Request
      .Open "GET", url, False
      .send
      rc = .StatusText
    End With
    Set Request = Nothing
    If rc = "OK" Then URLExists = True

    Exit Function
EndNow:
End Function
```